# Convert Java Nio Path to File. (not with toFile())

Tags: java, android, file, path, nio

I have an android project which API level is 18. when I convert a path to File (with `.toFile()`) it says need API level 26 and above.

so How do I convert java nio `path` to `File` reliable way?

here is source

```
OutputStream createStream(Path filepath){
    File file = filepath.toFile() // <--- android studio says need api level 26
    return new FileOutPutStream(file)
}
```

from the android developer site

java.nio.file.Files         added in API 26

Comment: Do you have access to the `toUri()` method ?

Comment: No, it says 26 and above.

Comment: @SKPanchal Please, post some source code, so that we could help you.

Comment: @jantursky source code added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `toString()` method of `Path`.

```
OutputStream createStream(Path filepath){
File file = new File(filepath.toString());
return new FileOutPutStream(file)
}
```

> > **[String toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toString())**
> >     Returns the string representation of this path.
> >     If this path was created by converting a path string using the getPath method then the path string returned by this method may differ from the original String used to create the path.
> >
> > The returned path string uses the default name separator to separate names in the path.